# Expo iOS app is crashing when fetching for new version

Tags: ios, react-native, crash, expo

I have installed the [expo-updates](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/updates/) library for our app. I just tried reproducing this [code snippet](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/updating-your-app/#manual-updates) which results in the app crashing on iOS - iPhones. Once the app is launched again from ExpoGo it works with the new version. The code works as expected on android (checks for updates, if there are updates it downloads them and reloads the app with the new app version). The crash is not affected by try catch, throwing errors, [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) does not pick the error up either.

Expo sdk version: 41

expo-updates version: 0.5.4

Managed workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by upgrading expo SDK to 44 and expo-updates to 0.11.5